# How to prevent creating duplicate row in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`project_site` model has attributes like `site_id`, `project_id` and `attendance_month`.

Before saving data into table, I want to check if same row already exists then I want to add error.

If same row doesn't exists, then I want to add row into table. I tried validate method on create but it did not work.

Current code in model:

`project_site.rb`

```
validates :attendance_month, :project_id, :site_id, presence: true
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-create_or_find_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you only want one record in the DB for a `:attendance_month`, `:project_id`, and `:site_id` record combination?

I would do this

Add a custom validation in the model

```
validate :validate_record_is_unique
```

Then for the method itself (you can change the message to whatever you want it to be obviously)

```
def validate_record_is_unique
  # Check if a matching record exists
  rec = ProjectSite.where('attendance_month = ? AND project_id = ? AND site_id = ?', self.attendance_month, self.project_id, self.site_id)

  if rec.count > 0
    errors.add :attendance_month, 'A record for this site and project already exist for that month.'
  end
end
```